# Error using Objective C typedef enum in Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift

I try to use `Reachability` class provided by Apple.

It has an Objective-C enum like this:

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
    NotReachable = 0,
    ReachableViaWiFi,
    ReachableViaWWAN
} NetworkStatus;
```

And in Swift I'm doing something like this:

```
if let networkReachability = notification.object as? Reachability {
    let remoteHostStatus = networkReachability.currentReachabilityStatus()
    let center = NotificationCenter.default
    var notificationKey: String

    if (remoteHostStatus == NetworkStatus.NotReachable) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> Type 'NetworkStatus' has no member 'NotReachable'

What am I doing wrong? How can I use that Objective-C `enum` in Swift?

Comment: Only enumerations marked with `NS_ENUM` are imported as Swift `enum` type. This is *documented* in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
    NotReachable = 0,
    ReachableViaWiFi,
    ReachableViaWWAN
} NetworkStatus;
```

This is an "ordinary" C enum. So it arrives into Swift with no namespacing; the names `NotReachable`, `ReachableViaWiFi`, and `ReachableViaWWAN` can be used *directly*. Note that there is no preceding dot (`.`).

Comment: For more on this topic, see my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_c_enums

Answer (score 1):

If you define your enum like follows, it will be accessible as `NetworkStatus.NotReachable`, etc.:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NetworkStatus) {
    NotReachable = 0,
    ReachableViaWiFi,
    ReachableViaWWAN
};
```